# Do not reset a timer after a pause/resume when it has already ended (difficult to explain)

Tags: android, if-statement, timer, resume

I'm a newbie in java android. I've done a lot of research on SO but couldn't find a case that matches mine.

I made an android app game with different timers. I implemented the pause/resume method, it works fine but big problem with the second timer: i would like this timer not to resume in return from a pause when it is already finished in the cycle of the activity. This timer corresponds to the action of a character in the game. I hope I explained myself well (sorry for my English, I'm French). thanks a lot for your help...

My ON PAUSE:

```
 protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        MyMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayerInstance().stopAudioFile();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("X", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("lastActivity", getClass().getName());
        editor.commit();
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mCountDownTimer = null;
        Timer2.cancel();
        Timer2 = null;
    }
```

My ON RESUME:

```
 protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MyMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayerInstance().resumeAudio();
        if (mCountDownTimer == null) {
            mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeRemaining, TIMER_INTERVAL) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    textView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d sec.", millisUntilFinished / 1000L));
                    mTimeRemaining = millisUntilFinished;
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(P39x.this, Lose15b.class);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(P39x.this, "time has passed...\n" +
                            "\n" +
                            "YOU HAVE LOST !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    View toastView = toast.getView();
                    TextView toastMessage = (TextView) toastView.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "SanvitoProLight.ttf");
                    toastMessage.setTypeface(typeface);
                    toastMessage.setTextSize(50);
                    toastMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.quiet);
                    toastMessage.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    toastMessage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    toast.show();
                    getMediaPlayerInstance().stopAudioFile();
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.collapse);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }.start();

            if (Timer2 == null) {
                Timer2 = new CountDownTimer(TIMERDURATION, TIMERINTERVAL) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        mTimeRemainin = millisUntilFinished;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        toast = Toast.makeText(P39x.this, "Find your way now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        View toastView = toast.getView();
                        TextView toastMessage = (TextView) toastView.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "SanvitoProLight.ttf");
                        toastMessage.setTypeface(typeface);
                        toastMessage.setTextSize(40);
                        toastMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                        toastMessage.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                        toastMessage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }.start();
```

I would like Timer2 not to resume in return from a pause when it is already finished in the cycle of the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want that the second timer not to restart if it has already finished at the activity. I think there are different ways to solve this problem. A solution could be to implement a boolean variable that holds the information whether the timer should continue or not.

```
Boolean startTimer = true;
```

In the Timer2 onFinish() function you set this var to false

```
Timer2 = new CountDownTimer(...){
   ....
     @Override
     public void onFinish() {
      ....
      startTimer = false;
     }
```

and in the onResume() function you use it:

```
protected void onResume(){
   ...
   if(startTimer){
       Timer2.start()
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm testing, your code works, however the application crashes half the time during onResume...

Comment: Could you show me the error message?

Comment: It's great, it works, I removed the ```Timer2 = null; ``` of onPause, that's what caused the crashes (but I don't see why it crashed the app).
Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

This is a lifecycle issue, move timer2 to onCreate() method instead of onResume because onResume get called after onPause() is active.